# CSS elements being separated / breaking / wrapping

Tags: css

Edit: fixed. Thanks everyone for the help ;)

Hello everyone,

I'm having a few problems with the blue bar elements being separated instead of being together.

Both elements "Notícias" and the blue bar are inside a div called "content". The blue bar is inside a span, and is created with 3 divs. One for the left image, the middle one is a repeating background and finally the third one with the last image.

Here's an image to ilustrate the problem: http://i52.tinypic.com/b3vhic.png

The code is the following:


`.barra .barra-azul {

 background: url(outros/barra_sidebar_e.png) no-repeat top left;

 display: inline-block;

 height: 14px;

 width: 7px;

}

.barra .barra-azul-meio {

 background: #56a3eb repeat-x;

 display: inline-block;

 height: 14px;

 width: 50%;

}

.barra .barra-azul-fim {

 background: url(outros/barra_sidebar_d.png) no-repeat top right;

 display: inline-block;

 height: 14px;

 width: 7px;

}`

And the html is:

```
<span class="barra">  
<div class="barra-azul"></div>  
<div class="barra-azul-meio"></div>  
<div class="barra-azul-fim"></div>  
</span>
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: you may want to float the divs, and nesting divs inside a span makes no sense :P

Comment: If i float the elements they will appear before the "Noticias" :S I've changed from span to div then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer without being able to experiment with the actual code and graphics. But you can start with adding the following.

```
.barra div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

If it doesn't work it would be great if you could post a link to a demo of bar.

Comment: Here's the link http://unitedgrounds.com/
I have Eric Meyer's CSS reset, so i guess that is added to every div automatically...

Comment: For me it looks OK if you use `display: block; float: left;` on all elements. Then add a new element below them `<div class="clear"></div>` and set `.clear { clear: both; }`.

Comment: Should i apply the display:block; float: left; to the noticias heading aswell?

Comment: No, that one should not be floated.

Comment: Ok i've applied your code and it's working a lot better now, yet the blue bar should be positioned on the right side of "Noticias" :S

Comment: Please see the code suggested by coreyward as that one is way more clean and the result is the same. Just looking forward to placing the image next to "Noticias" now...

Comment: Ok, in that case the h1 can be floated to the left. Then you'll have to set the margins on .barra and width on the h1 until it looks good.

Comment: And it's done! :) All i had to do was flaot h1, put a width on it and add a margin-top on .barra! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that they're *inline*-block elements per your CSS rules and you have whitespace between them in your markup. You should either float them, or position them absolutely.

HTML:

```
<div class="barra">
  <div class="barra-azul"></div>
  <div class="barra-azul-meio"></div>  
  <div class="barra-azul-fim"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.barra > div {
  float: left;
  height: 14px;
  width: 7px;
}

.barra .barra-azul {
  background: url(outros/barra_sidebar_e.png) no-repeat top left;
}

.barra .barra-azul-meio {
  background: #56a3eb repeat-x;
  width: 50%;
}

.barra .barra-azul-fim {
  background: url(outros/barra_sidebar_d.png) no-repeat top right;
}
```

That also cuts out a bunch of duplication you had going on.

Comment: If i float the elements, they will appear before "Noticias".. Should this be happening? If needs be, please use the demo link http://unitedgrounds.com/

Comment: I just did it and it works fine. Screenshot: http://cl.ly/0b161U0m402v0s2n3a0q — I'll update with CSS.

Comment: I've used the code suggested by 9muses above and it did work, now i'm just trying to position the div on the right side of "Noticias"

Comment: I've updated the website with your code now, thanks for the optimization :) Yet, how should i put the bar next to "Noticias" now?

Comment: 9Muses has provided the rest of the code. Thank you very much for your help!